# Grab items from dictionary based on length of lists they are mapped to

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a `dict` which has the following format

```
d = {
    1: [m1, m2],
    2: [m3, m5, m6],
    3: [m4],
    4: [m7, m8]
}
```

And I'd like to pull out the information when I iterate through to the get the largest lists first.  But because dictionaries are unordered storage when I do something like

```
for n, my_list in d.items():
    # do stuff..
```

I can't guarantee I will get the `2: [m3, m5, m6]` entry first.  Is there a clean way to do that?

Comment: If you always want to pull the largest value out first, a [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) might be a better data structure than a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to sort the items by the length of the value.

```
items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: len(i[1]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to order the dictionary by their values size and sort them accordingly.

Ans: sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: len(x[1]))